# Possible to uncomment some code with Proguard/Android

Tags: android, proguard

In my code, I have some urls that refer to my local server, that I manually change, when I export my project to apk, like this :

```
 BASE_URL = "http://loc.server.com";
 //BASE_URL = "http://prod.server.com";
```

I'm wondering if I can automatically uncomment my second line with Proguard (or another way), to be sure that I will never send a apk, which refer to my local server.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve same effect with DEBUG flag

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    BASE_URL = "http://loc.server.com";
} else {
    BASE_URL = "http://prod.server.com";
}
```

Comment: Ok, this can be a solution. No solution without adding some case-by-case code ?

Comment: This is most simplistic solution I know. And others don't have any advantages against this one.